# How to trigger a hover effect for a Typography and StyledTextField at the same time using MUI and Typescript

Tags: material-ui, hover, react-typescript

```
 <Typography 
        id = "first_text"
        sx= {{
          fontWeight: "regular", 
          fontSize: "18px", 
          marginTop: "-4px", 
          marginLeft: "8px", 
          color: "#888",
          '&:hover': {
            color: "#252525"
         },
         }}>
         First Name*
        </Typography>
<StyledTextField..... (didn't put the whole code here but you get the picture, haha)>
```

I tried putting it all in one box and adding a hover state to that box, maybe I did it wrong but it did not work. I see that similar questions were asked but I am new to MUI and not quite sure how to work with it.

Comment: Did you try using a `state` which triggers to `true` onMouseEnter and turns `false` onMouseLeave?

Comment: Wrap them in the same parent element and then apply the `:hover` styling (color) to the parent, to be inherited by the children.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap them in a `Box` component and use the `sx` prop to apply the hover styles to the children elements. For example:

```
<Box
  sx={{
    "&:hover": {
      "& #first_text": {
        color: "#252525",
      },
      "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
        borderColor: "#252525",
      },
    },
  }}
>
  <Typography
    id="first_text"
    sx={{
      fontWeight: "regular",
      fontSize: "18px",
      marginTop: "-4px",
      marginLeft: "8px",
      color: "#888",
    }}
  >
    First Name*
  </Typography>
  <TextField variant="outlined" />
</Box>
```

You can see the whole example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-lucy-y2vhz3?file=/Demo.tsx).